# Unable to Create a View in Databricks with certain name

Tags: pyspark, databricks, databricks-sql

Can someone explain why certain view names return the an AnalysisException: Error

For example if I enter the

```
%sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW simphony.funduniverse

as 
select last_day(add_months(current_date(),-1))
```

I get the error

```
AnalysisException: `simphony`.`funduniverse` is not a view;
```

But I can enter absolutely any other name and I won't get any error e.g

```
%sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW simphony.funduniverseXP

as 
select last_day(add_months(current_date(),-1))
```

The above won't give any error.

It would appear it's just with the name `funduniverse` - although I know that must crazy talk.

Any thoughts?

Comment: what you get if you do `describe simphony.funduniverse`, etc.? most probably you have another object (table, function, ...) with the same name